# Can I use module name as a 'variable' in Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use the name of the module as a variable to send to a function and specify/restrict some object with it? Thanks!

#### module1.py

```
def foo(a, b):
    return (a + b) / 2.0
```

#### module2.py

```
def foo(a, b):
    return 2.0 * a*b / (a+b)
```

#### file3.py

```
import module1
import module2

def do(a, b, module_name):
   return module_name.foo(a, b)
```

Comment: what happened when you tried this?

Comment: What type is `module_name`? Is it a string (perhaps from user input), or is it an actual module object? In general, using variable names as data is a bad idea (variable names are for the programmer, not the user). If you want to associate names with objects (such as modules), you should use a dictionary (and indeed, Python does use dictionaries under the covers to implement some kinds of variables).

Comment: I think this question would be more clear if you provided a runnable example... just add `print(do(1,2,"module1"))` to the bottom and you have it.

Comment: @Blckknght, thank you for educational comments, I am very new in python coding(or coding), and I did notice to use a string truly not a very good idea just as you said. Do you have some further reading for me what shall I do for my case or general cases? thanks!

Comment: @tdelaney,@Paul H thanks. I didn't get through when I had a first try on this probably due to some other errors. But actually it is ok. I appreciate all the answers you gave which inspired me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Following your question, I assumed that you want to be able to invoke the foo method **of any locally imported modules**, providing args + module_name (as a string, like the variable name suggests).

Using `locals()` instead of `sys.modules` narrows the search to the modules imported in this file.

## My solution:

```
import inspect

import module1
import module2


def do(a, b, module_name):
   module = locals().get(module_name)
   if inspect.ismodule(module):
       return module.foo(a, b)
   raise NameError('no such module imported with this name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access modules in the form of a dictionary for easy lookup using `sys.modules`:

```
import module1
import module2
import sys

def do(a, b, module_name):
    return sys.modules[module_name].foo(a, b)
```

This way they can be called for example:

```
do(3, 5, 'module1')  # returns 4.0
do(3, 5, 'module2')  # returns 3.75
```

Comment: Why the down votes, isn't this what the OP is asking? Referencing a module by it's name?

Comment: My guess would be that downvoters have misunderstood the question. An example, e.g. `do(3, 5, 'module1')`, `do(3, 5, 'module2')` might help.

Comment: Thanks @ZeroPiraeus, I guess you are right. Will expand the question with those.

Comment: @bosnjak, deleted my answer as I misunderstood that question at first glance. I think the down votes are not entirely expected for this suitable answer. Cheers!

Comment: The OP seems to be asking if you can pass a module in as an argument to a function, not as a representation of a string. his question is getting downvoted because he or she clearly hasn't tried it the code provided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what he is asking, and also pretty sure he is having a hard time explaining his question properly. So I agree on that part :)

Comment: Thank you all for discussion, I've learnt from you guys. Do you prefer transferring a string or a module?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve. Ideally, none - if you can organize your code in a better way. If you can't, then probably having a reference to the module is better than having to sanitize and verify strings.